# UITableView text overtop of my custom section header?

Tags: ios, xamarin

My issue is that when I scroll in my UITableView, the row text ends up right over top of my section header text. When the next section header comes along, it forces the previous one to scroll off (which is as expected).

Here's my code
        public override UIView GetViewForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            var myHeader = new UIView ();
            myHeader.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 0, 320, 30);

```
        var lbl = new UILabel ();
        lbl.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 8, 320, 20);
        lbl.Text = TitleForHeader (tableView, section);
        lbl.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (18f);
        lbl.Center = myHeader.Center;

        myHeader.AddSubview(lbl);
        return myHeader;
    }

    public override float GetHeightForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return GetViewForHeader (tableView, section).Frame.Height;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Head-desk moment.

The default behaviour for a view is to have a transparent background. Once I set the myHeader.BackgroundColor = tableview.BackgroundColor it worked as I expected.